# Question on deriving cosine function from exponential function.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I have a simple question. I'm having trouble deriving the cosine function from the following:

$$\frac{1}{2} (e^{-i x} + i e^{ix}) = \cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

How does $i$ lead to the variable shifting by $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$?

Thanks.

Comment: You might look at $\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta$ and $\cos \frac\pi4 =\sin \frac\pi4=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Set $X:=x+\pi/4$ and use the fact that $e^{i \pi/4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$

Comment: You could start by replacing $e^{-ix}$ and $e^{ix}$ by the equivalent formulas in terms of sin and cos, multiplying through by $i$ and by $\frac12$ as shown on the left side of the equation, and then collecting the real and imaginary terms that result. What you have written says that the sum of the imaginary terms on the left side will be zero. Is it? What do you find? If you show your work you should at least get to a point where someone can give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your expression is correct? When $x=0$, $\frac{1}{2}(ie^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ is $\frac{1}{2}(1+i)$ and $\cos(x+\pi/4)$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

The proof is-

We may set (where $x$ is real) $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}(ie^{ix}+e^{-ix})$. We wish to find (if $f(x)=u(x)+iv(x)$ where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued) expressions for $u$ and for $v$. Write $ie^{ix}$ as $i(\cos x+i\sin x)$, hence $ie^{ix}=-\sin x+i\cos x$.  Hence $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}[(\cos x-\sin x)+i(\cos x-\sin x)]$. Hence $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin x)=\frac{1}{2}(ie^{ix}+e^{-ix})$. And, $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin x)$ is $\omega \times \cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$ where $\omega=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ (or $\omega=e^{i\frac{1}{4}\pi}$).

Comment: Shoot, I made a mistake in the expression and I understand where my issue was coming from. Thank you for the clear explanation!